# Как правильно создать массив на основании DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

У меня есть DataFrame. Вот пример:

```
0    457.33402
1    424.44000
2    394.79599
3    408.90399
4    398.82101
5    402.15201
6    435.79098
7    423.20499
8    411.57400
9    404.42499
10   399.51999
11   377.18100
12   375.46701
13   386.94400
14   383.61499
15   375.07199
16   359.51199
17   328.86600
18   320.51001
19   330.07901
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

Я хочу пройтись по нему и создать массив данных, таким образом, чтобы взять значение и к нему добавить `n` значений, которые идут после него. Например:

```
[[457.33402, 424.44000, 394.79599], [424.44000, 394.79599, 408.90399], ...
[328.86600, 320.51001, 330.07901]]
```

Делаю это вот так:

```
quotes = []
for i in df.values:
    s = df[i:i+30].values
    quotes.append(s)
```

При выполнении кода, получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [457.334015] of <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Я использовал `iloc`, но ошибка не пропала.

Как правильно сделать то, что я хочу?

Comment: а что вы дальше планируете делать с полученными списками? В Pandas уже реализованы функции плавающих окон ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас i это значение, а не индекс записи. Нужно так:

```
quotes = []
for num, i in df.items():
    s = df[num:num+30].tolist()
    quotes.append(s)
```

И это Series, а не DataFrame.

Answer (score 3):

Подозреваю, что данные списки понадобились для выполнения агрегирования по скользящему окну.

[В Pandas этот функционал уже реализован...](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html)

Исходный DF:

```
In [80]: df
Out[80]:
    Adj Close
0   457.33402
1   424.44000
2   394.79599
3   408.90399
4   398.82101
5   402.15201
6   435.79098
7   423.20499
8   411.57400
9   404.42499
10  399.51999
11  377.18100
12  375.46701
13  386.94400
14  383.61499
15  375.07199
16  359.51199
17  328.86600
18  320.51001
19  330.07901
```

ищем среднее значение в плавающем окне (из 3х элементов):

```
In [81]: df["Adj Close"].rolling(3).mean()
Out[81]:
0            NaN
1            NaN
2     425.523337
3     409.379993
4     400.840330
5     403.292337
6     412.254667
7     420.382660
8     423.523323
9     413.067993
10    405.172993
11    393.708660
12    384.056000
13    379.864003
14    382.008667
15    381.876993
16    372.732990
17    354.483327
18    336.296000
19    326.485007
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

ищем максимальное значение в плавающем окне (из 3х элементов):

```
In [82]: df["Adj Close"].rolling(3, min_periods=1).max()
Out[82]:
0     457.33402
1     457.33402
2     457.33402
3     424.44000
4     408.90399
5     408.90399
6     435.79098
7     435.79098
8     435.79098
9     423.20499
10    411.57400
11    404.42499
12    399.51999
13    386.94400
14    386.94400
15    386.94400
16    383.61499
17    375.07199
18    359.51199
19    330.07901
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```